# php trait not found?

Tags: php, php-7

Im not using laravel or any framework, i am following the tutorial in O['reilly modern php book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491905018). I'm  using php version 7;

and when using traits i get this error

```
Fatal error: Trait 'Geocodable' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli9/RetailStore.php on line 5
```

here is the following code

Geocodable.php

```
<?php

trait Geocodable{

    protected $address;

    protected $geocoder;

    protected $geocoderResult;

    public function setGeocoder(\Geocoder\Geocoder $geocoder)
    {
        $this->geocoder = $geocoder;
    }

    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }


    public function getLatitude()
    {
        if(!isset($this->geocoderResult)){
            $this->geocodeAddress();
        }

        return $this->geocoderResult->first()->getLatitude();
    }

    public function getLongitude()
    {
        if(!isset($this->geocoderResult)){
            $this->geocodeAddress();
        }

        return $this->geocoderResult->first()->getLongitude();
    }


    public function getcodeAddress()
    {
        $this->geocoderResult = $this->gecoder->geocode($this->address);

        return true;
    }
}
```

RetailStore.php

```
<?php

class RetailStore
{
    use Geocodable;
}
```

Comment: Do you `include` Geocodable.php?

Comment: Have you tried `require_once 'Geocodable.php';`?

Comment: i have not, i was under the impression that using `use geocodable;` would include the file and grab the methods from there

Comment: @AbraCadaver i have to require files using namespaces and traits ?

Comment: Read the duplicate questions about autoloading. In short, yes, you have to load them. But set up an autoloader and your code will work as you're expecting

Comment: oh ok, now i understand, thanks